# Comparing Images to associated Grids

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps

Im trying to o a drag and drop game, where the user has to sort 10 numbered images into 2 grids, one odd and one even.

We have the drag and drop working, but it skips the first part of the if statement and goes straight to the else. 
So the images wont sort. Any ideas where I could be going wrong?

**XAML**

```
<Grid PointerMoved="ptr_moved" >
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Assets/oddEveBck.png"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Image Tag="one" x:Name="one" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="179" Margin="-14,609,0,-20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="224" Source="Assets/OddEve/Fish1.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" PointerPressed="fish1_pressed" PointerReleased="fish1_released" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform Rotation="-15.903"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
    <Image Tag="two" x:Name="two" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="179" Margin="254,522,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="224" Source="Assets/OddEve/Fish2.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" PointerPressed="fish2_pressed" PointerReleased="fish2_released">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform Rotation="5.071"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
    <Image Tag="three" x:Name="three" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="179" Margin="101,525,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="224" Source="Assets/OddEve/Fish3.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" PointerPressed="fish3_pressed" PointerReleased="fish3_released">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform Rotation="28.652"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
    <Image Tag="four" x:Name="four" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="179" Margin="508,635,0,-46" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="224" Source="Assets/OddEve/Fish4.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" PointerPressed="fish4_pressed" PointerReleased="fish4_released" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform Rotation="-15.903"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
    <Image Tag="five" x:Name="backBtn" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="134" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Back.png" Tapped="backBtn_Tapped"/>
    <Image x:Name="five" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="179" Margin="180,623,0,-34" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="224" Source="Assets/OddEve/Fish5.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" PointerPressed="fish5_pressed" PointerReleased="fish5_released" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform Rotation="1.614"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
    <Image Tag="six" x:Name="six" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="179" Margin="456,537,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="224" Source="Assets/OddEve/Fish6.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" PointerPressed="fish6_pressed" PointerReleased="fish6_released" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform Rotation="-15.903"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
    <Image Tag="seven" x:Name="seven" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="179" Margin="586,549,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="224" Source="Assets/OddEve/Fish7.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" PointerPressed="fish7_pressed" PointerReleased="fish7_released" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform Rotation="3.14"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
    <Image Tag="eight" x:Name="eight" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="179" Margin="334,601,0,-12" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="224" Source="Assets/OddEve/Fish8.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" PointerPressed="fish8_pressed" PointerReleased="fish8_released" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform Rotation="-15.903"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
    <Grid Tag="evenGrid" x:Name="evenGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="199" Margin="943,497,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142" RenderTransformOrigin="0.492,0.503" />
    <Grid Tag="oddGrid" x:Name="oddGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="199" Margin="1090,497,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150"/>

</Grid>
```

**XAML.CS**

```
 private void fish1_pressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            holding = sender as Image;
            imageOffset = e.GetCurrentPoint(holding).Position;

    }

    private async void fish1_released(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (oddGrid == one.Tag)
        {
            holding = null;
            one.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        else
        {
            MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Not even try again!!");
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
            holding = null;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `if` statement:

```
if (oddGrid == one.Tag)
```

In this case, `oddGrid` is a `Grid` object, and `one.Tag` is a `string` with the value `"one"`. Clearly they are not equal, so the `else` block is executed instead. But it's not clear from the code sample what you're actually trying to test. Presumably you also do some work in the `ptr_moved` event handler that isn't shown here.